# How to update value in client site using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am using React in front-end and Node and MongoDB in Back-end. I have created a custom hook from where I am loading the data. The following is the custom hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useItems = (id) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/inventory/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setItem(data));
  }, [id]);

  return [item];
};

export default useItems;
```

And this is the component where I am calling the custom hook to load the data.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Inventory.css";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useItems from "../../hooks/useItems";

const Inventory = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [item] = useItems(id);

  const quantityDecrease = (newQuantity) => {
    let quantity = parseInt(newQuantity) - 1;
    const updateQuantity = { quantity };
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/inventory/${id}`;

    fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateQuantity),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("success", data);
        alert("saved");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <p className="inventory-textbox">
                  <strong>Quantity :</strong> {item.quantity}
                </p>
              </div>
                <button onClick={() => quantityDecrease(item.quantity)}>
                   Delivered
                </button>
          </div>
  );
};

export default Inventory;
```

Whenever the Delivered button is clicked the quantityDecrease function is executed and the quantity of the item is decreased by one. Now, my database is working fine. I am being able to update both client and server site but I have to reload the page in order to see the change in the ui. Is there a way I do not have to reload to see the change?

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish your requirement. Take least effort is to use current Mongo with socket. Or you can just switch to real-time database, they handle it for you by default. Something like Firestore/firebase, RethinkDb.

Comment: You can also use "long polling" where in your react app, you actively query your database every 10s, see if it updated, if so, you set the state, react will update the UI for you. This is just to show you what could you do. To do it properly is another story.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to look it up. But I already solved it by keeping the response in a state.

Answer (score 0):

try using the item data as useEffect dependency. it may solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).